# How to use array for if condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm looking for some help to automate this process.

Here's my full page of code.
http://www.privatepaste.com/65bbd73d3b
Sorry I used privatepaste, but it was too much code for me to format nicely by putting 4 lines infront of each (if there's a fast way to do this, let me know for my next SO question!)

Basically, if you look at line 53, I have this.

```
$checkdonors = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE membergroupids LIKE '%33'");
```

I'm trying to make it so it checks if the userid's membergroupids field contains 33, which it checks fine.  However, I want to add it to an if condition, shown on line 77.

```
<td <?php if ($tuserid==$checkdonors) { ?> style="background-color:#D0F2CD;" <?php } elseif ($tids=='1' AND $toonid==$tid) { ?> style="background-color:#FFD2F9; <?php } ?>">
```

Because, on the next td, I have..

```
<td <?php if ($tuserid=='602' || $tuserid=='232' || $tuserid=='200' || $tuserid=='563' || $tuserid=='532') { ?>
```

Those 5 userid's (602,232,200,563,532) are the users I have in membergroupids 33, but I had to do it manually.

I'd like to automate the process, so I don't have to add a new $tuserid=='userid' every time a member is added to membergroupids '33'.

How can I do this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: what is the reason why you are explicitly checking those IDs? and why are they hardcoded?

Comment: Hi @Ghost  The users who are in those userid's are VIPs (staff, to be specific).  I want there td-cell background color to be different from the others.  It's working fine hardcoded, and as new ones are added, I can just keep adding more id's to it.  However, I'd like to automate it, and I think arrays are used, but if you can tell by the old coding methods I use in my privatepaste, I don't know how to use arrays.  I'm a beginner.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not introduce a role concept or an admin flag an check for a a given role or if the admin flag is set?

Comment: so those `602,232,200,563,532` are those vips ? and they are the result of `SELECT userid FROM user WHERE membergroupids LIKE '%33'`?

Comment: @ZombieHunter could you explain more?

Comment: @Ghost yes, those are the userid's that show up in the $checkdonors mysql query.

Comment: @llw I'd assume Zonbie is suggesting you have alongside userid something like is_vip (1 or 0) making your `select` statement `SELECT userid, vip...` You then loop through as you do but rather than checking for a specific user ID you instead check to see if `is_vip == 1`

Comment: Oh.. I see what you mean.  I should've thought of that beforehand!  @J Young

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could just do something like this:

```
// You could gather all of those ids first
$donors = array();
$checkdonors = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE membergroupids LIKE '%33'");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkdonors)) {
    $donors[] = $r['userid'];
}
```

So that when you're inside that other loop. You could use `in_array()`:

```
if(in_array($tuserid, $donors)) {
    // if that current id in the current loop is one of those donors
    // do something
}
```

Sidenote: If possible, switch to the better mysql extension which is mysqli or use PDO instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Ghost, this worked beautifully.  In the past, people have suggested to switch to mysqli or use PDO, but I haven't learned either.  I run a vBulletin powered forum, and I learned the HTML, php, mysql, etc by running vBulletin forums  for years.  While I'd like to learn PDO or mysqli, I don't know where to start, and this basic PHP (I guess you can call it that) is doing the job.  Waiting for a minute to pass so I can give you best answer. :)